# SecurityException error when calling CLR function "Revisited"

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, security, permissions, sqlclr

I am running SQL Server locally only.
I am building a project with VS 2017 community.
I created a CLR procedure, and uploaded it as an assembly successfully.
The class and the method are public.
I created a SQL standard proc to call the clr proc with permissions_set = external_access.
Trustworthy is on.
Alter authorization is set to sa.

All it does is execute a bat file:
     cmd.exe c:\temp\test.bat

But I'm still getting an error 6522 Security Exception.

When I run the method as a console app, it runs perfect. But in SQL Server,
no go.

I'd be very grateful for any advice - this is my first attempt with CLR.

```
Code:
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;


public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void RunTestBat()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo pPStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        pPStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Temp";

        pPStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        pPStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@" /C test.bat");

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = pPStartInfo;        
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [SQLCLR] proc with permissions_set = external_access

That is the problem. You are using threading, which requires the `PERMISSION_SET` to be `UNSAFE`.

Also, while Visual Studio offers little help in this area, you generally should not set your database's to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`. Yes, it is the simple fix for this annoying problem, but it isn't a good / long-term fix, especially for production. There is a way (two ways, actually) to set things up correctly to use an Asymmetric Key / Strong Name Key or Certificate to handle the security. Both approaches can be made to work within the structure of Visual Studio / SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). Some info here (an answer of mine here on S.O.):

[CLR Strict Security on SQL Server 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086646/577765)

And two blog posts of mine, each dealing with a different approach:

- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/)
- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 3: “CLR strict security” – Solution 2](https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/)

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit:

[SQLCLR.org](https://SQLCLR.org/)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much for the guidance!

Comment: Solomon - I wanted to give you an upvote, but apparently I'm too new to StackOverflow to allow it. I hope the comment serves to help. You're one of the few who actually answered the question instead of asking for more useless details!

Comment: @Coreysan Thanks, is ok. Yeah, I think you need 20 pts in order to vote. And again, you are welcome. Of course, I don't see that anyone has asked for any details on the question. Either way, glad the info helped out :)