# Error publish user defined type in C# to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express edition and Visual Studio 2017.

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nczucm60YF0&t=2s, but I get this error:

> Executing publish script on database 'database name'

Full message is:

> Creating [SQLCLRUDTypeDemo]... (94,1):
>   SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 10343, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE or ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'SQLCLRUDTypeDemo' with the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS option failed because the 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure is set to 1. Microsoft recommends that you sign the assembly with a certificate or asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission. Alternatively, you can trust the assembly using sp_add_trusted_assembly.
>
> (94,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.
>   The executed script:
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY [SQLCLRUDTypeDemo]
>   AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
>   FROM 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
>   An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

What is the solution? I didn't find this problem anywhere. I found with an error in SQL Server, but not in C#.

Comment: Assembly use for CLR types must be signed or the security option disabled. **Read and search for the actual/relevant error**: “CREATE or ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly '..' with the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS option failed because the 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure is set to 1...” - after searching for the relevant error, what question(s) remain?

Comment: I tried with exec sp_configure 'clr enable', 1 reconfigure but it gives me an error. I solved with this: EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security', 0;
RECONFIGURE;

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't find this problem anywhere. I found with an error in SQL Server, but not in C#.

There error is not in .NET or C#. This is a permissions error coming from SQL Server. When searching for info on errors in SQL Server, you should, at the very least, include the "Msg" number and "Level". For example: `"Msg 10343, Level 14"` should be part of what you search for, including the double-quotes. It also helps to include `"SQL Server"` as part of the search term.

For info on how to properly sign and publish SQLCLR assemblies *without* disabling security (and even within the context of Visual Studio), please see my answer to another S.O. question, especially the second part (below the horizontal line):

[CLR Strict Security on SQL Server 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086646/577765)