# Visual Studio 2019 SSDT project SQLCLR signing not generating signed DLL

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

I used Visual Studio 2019 to create a SSDT project. Added a SQL CLR C# user defined function.

Open project properties page, in the SQLCLR tab, click Signing... button to check the "Sign the assembly", create a new key file. But after building the project, the generated DLL is not signed. There is no digital signature for the DLL.

How can I sign the SQL CLR DLL using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that the DLL is not signed? Did you inspect the DLL with a tool that can check for strong names (which is different than using a certificate to sign the assembly / DLL)? **SN.EXE** is what is used to strongly name the assembly. And it can extract a strong-name as well to confirm that it indeed has a strong name.

I suspect that the DLL / assembly is strongly named (i.e. signed) but that it cannot be deployed because Visual Studio (and more specifically, SSDT, which handles the building of the SQL script and deployment) has *never* understood the concept of SQLCLR security (probably because SSDT Database Projects are just that, *database*-level, not instance-level). So, unfortunately, we are left to deal with *proper* deployments ourselves ("proper" meaning *not* enabling `TRUSTWORTHY` for the DB).

I have instructions for two different approaches to this problem, both working with SQL Server 2017 and newer (older versions do not have the absurd and counter-productive "CLR strict security" server config option), *and* both being automatable.

- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/)
- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 3: “CLR strict security” – Solution 2](https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/)

For more details and explanation, please see my answer to the following question (also here on S.O.):

[CLR Strict Security on SQL Server 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086646/577765)