# How to recover Service Broker after restoring database?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, service-broker

After db restoring on other server the Service Broker is stopped.
The restored db has a Trustworthy Off and now I set it to On to run Broker again.
I understand that it is bad practice. Especially after reading articles by solomon-rutzky.
I have made as Solomon advised for SQLCLR UNSAFE functions without setting database to TRUSTWORTHY ON. It works fine!

How to restore Broker working in case TRUSTWORTHY OFF?

Comment: How was Service Broker configured originally? Did the original installation have `TRUSTWORTHY` enabled? Or was it using a certificate? If `TRUSTWORTHY` was enabled initially, then it makes sense to need to enable it upon restore as that setting is always disabled upon restore. If using a certificate, that _might_ need to be installed in `[master]` first (and would imply that such a certificate is already installed on the original instance). That and what Ben suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trustworthy isn't required to run Service Broker. There is, however, an option that you can pass to the `RESTORE` statement that is probably what you need. Quoting [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#service_broker_with_options):

> ENABLE_BROKER
>
> Specifies that Service Broker message delivery is
> enabled at the end of the restore so that messages can be sent
> immediately. By default Service Broker message delivery is disabled
> during a restore. The database retains the existing Service Broker
> identifier.

If you didn't do this, there is still hope! Post-restore, you can issue an `alter databse [yourDB] set enable_broker;`. Note, this requires exclusive database access, so you might also need to add `with rollback immediate` or similar to the `alter database` statement.