# Alter assembly permission set to Safe

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to alter the permission set for all the assemblies under a database at once?

I am seeing the error `Assembly 'Logger' cannot be loaded because this edition of SQL Server only supports SAFE assemblies.` So I want to change the permission from Unsafe to Safe for all the assemblies under a particular database.

Help appreciated!!

Comment: Is this something useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639213/how-to-grant-the-database-owner-dbo-the-external-access-assembly-permission ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/clr-strict-security?view=sql-server-2017