# How to grant unsafe assembly to a username found dynamically?

Tags: sql-server

I have to register a DLL in a SQL Server from a legacy project, the bad thing is that I don't have the DLL nor the source code, just what I have is the binary string obtained from the Create Scripts option on my database. I'm trying to use the following code:

```
USE [master]
DECLARE @CurrentUserName varchar(MAX)
SET @CurrentUserName = SUSER_SNAME()
SELECT @CurrentUserName
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO @CurrentUserName
```

The last line is giving me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near @CurrentUserName. Expecting ID, NULL, PUBLIC or
>   QUOTED_ID

I'm creating this script for giving my new team members a script to setup their DEV environments the first day without giving them a large manual with instructions because we learned that as our process of setup is huge many mistakes happen.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you need to use a command like `GRANT` with a variable, consider dynamic SQL.

Comment: Found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25848214/8803059), but still curious if there's a way semejant to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--You Have to use Dynamic SQL 

USE [master]
DECLARE @CurrentUserName VARCHAR(MAX),@String_SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CurrentUserName = SUSER_SNAME()
SELECT @CurrentUserName
--GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO @CurrentUserName

SET @String_SQL=''
SET @String_SQL =N'GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO '+@CurrentUserName+''

PRINT @String_SQL
EXEC (@String_SQL)
```